# Break down number into thousands,hundreds,etc

Tags: php, math, currency

I'm currently putting together a cheque printing solution for my company. When printing the cheque you need to print the number of millions,hundred thousands,ten thousands,thousands, hundreds,tens and units (pounds/dollars/euros etc ) from the amount being paid.

In the case of 111232.23 the following is correctly output from the code I have written below. I cant help feeling that there is a more efficient or reliable method of doing this? Does anyone know of a library/class math technique that does this?

```
float(111232.23)
Array
(
    [100000] => 1
    [10000] => 1
    [1000] => 1
    [100] => 2
    [10] => 3
    [1] => 2
)

<?php

$amounts = array(111232.23,4334.25,123.24,3.99);

function cheque_format($amount)
{
    var_dump($amount);
    #no need for millions
    $levels = array(100000,10000,1000,100,10,1);
    do{
        $current_level = current($levels);
        $modulo = $amount % $current_level;
        $results[$current_level] = $div = number_format(floor($amount) / $current_level,0);
        if($div)
        {
            $amount -= $current_level * $div;
        }
    }while($modulo && next($levels));

print_r($results);
}

foreach($amounts as $amount)
{
 cheque_format($amount);
}
?>
```

Comment: you do know that in php you could simply split the number at the decimal separator and then for-loop from the last position (length) to the first (0)? While i admire your spirit to do this the mathematical way i don't think it's going to be faster.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just re-wrote the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function that PHP has. My suggestion is to use the PHP function rather than to re-write it.

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

Comment: I do need the actual numbers as they have to be placed in specific boxes on the cheque

Comment: @Leo Then use the PHP function to echo out the numbers, but keep the original data intact.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what the PHP script would be for this, but if you have 10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1 as the things you need the amounts of.  How many 10,000's in amount $dollar?

```
floor($dollar/10000)
```

how many thousands?

```
floor(($dollar%10000)/1000)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer for the question, but the following also break down the decimals.

```
function cheque_format($amount, $decimals = true, $decimal_seperator = '.')
{
    var_dump($amount);

    $levels = array(100000, 10000, 1000, 100, 10, 5, 1);
    $decimal_levels = array(50, 20, 10, 5, 1);

    preg_match('/(?:\\' . $decimal_seperator . '(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/', (string)$amount, $match);
    $d = isset($match[1]) ? $match[1] : 0;

    foreach ( $levels as $level )
    {
        $level = (float)$level;
        $results[(string)$level] = $div = (int)(floor($amount) / $level);
        if ($div) $amount -= $level * $div;
    }

    if ( $decimals ) {
        $amount = $d;
        foreach ( $decimal_levels as $level )
        {
            $level = (float)$level;
            $results[$level < 10 ? '0.0'.(string)$level : '0.'.(string)$level] = $div = (int)(floor($amount) / $level);
            if ($div) $amount -= $level * $div;
        }
    }

    print_r($results);
}
```